# How to change Google Chrome User-Agent string on iPadOS

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, ipados

I want to change my user-agent string for a reason, so I want to know; Is there a way to change the Google Chrome user-agent string on iPadOS 14.5.1? chrome://version shows

```
Google Chrome   90.0.4430.78 (Official Build) stable (64-bit)
Revision    5efbfe317610ba1c007cae2c17a1387b25023954-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#1273}
OS  iOS
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 14_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/90.0.4430.78 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Command Line    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E45C7263-8110-4FD7-816A-7F1716519B62/stable.app/Chrome --gaia-url=https://accounts.google.com/ --lso-url=https://accounts.google.com/ --google-apis-url=https://www.googleapis.com/ --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Variations  90a7075b-ca7d8d80
16b16054-ca7d8d80
59b6f412-ca7d8d80
60d4b352-fcb701
12d606a9-3d47f4f4
d7561e8c-ca7d8d80
b3249ec4-ca7d8d80
a9ef513c-ca7d8d80
aed6e5d4-ca7d8d80
3095aa95-3f4a17df
9f9c8297-377be55a
a582a1b8-ad75ce17
a2cb081b-377be55a
b9b6628c-ca7d8d80
ab801be6-ca7d8d80
3042ad4b-ca7d8d80
fe9029fc-ca7d8d80
7d236693-12ede6a2
ec9552e2-ca7d8d80
51d03642-5c0c03aa
2c79286f-ca7d8d80
b2e830b4-ca7d8d80
6a17d209-4bedef5
5c5e100f-ca7d8d80
ee453243-ca7d8d80
141cc710-ca7d8d80
990fd033-ca7d8d80
9e5c75f1-766fa2d
c6643b2c-91c810ef
33d2103a-3f4a17df
5fe247df-ca7d8d80
4f6db7c8-ca7d8d80
a375a87b-377be55a
f31b480d-ca7d8d80
6a9d5557-ca7d8d80
12d6c444-ca7d8d80
1354da85-ca7d8d80
494d8760-52325d43
3ac60855-486e2a9c
63dcb6a3-6995a802
e706e746-e00d173c
f296190c-92bb99a9
4442aae2-6bdfffe7
f690cf64-d7f6b13c
ed1d377-e1cc0f14
75f0f0a0-d7f6b13c
e2b18481-bd104136
e7e71889-4ad60575
547e761a-a38ca7f0
8db2e42f-aed3cc39
5e31bb48-75513c66
a461b170-ca7d8d80
Compiler    LLVM clang
```

So please can someone answer my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: **No, you can't.** Unless there're any other browsers that support switching User Agent natively.

It's sad news, since all browsers on iOS/iPadOS share the same technology (WebKit) under the hood as Safari, per requirement by Apple. You can't install existing Chrome extensions to switch UA string either (also not doable on Chrome for Android).

WebKit surely provided abilities to change UA string, but Chrome on iOS sadly didn't expose this feature.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. While it isn't what I was hoping, I'll still upvote the answer.